# Want to put three programs ino one, and ask the user which he wants to proceed

Tags: java

Here's the three programs I wrote, into one. But it doesn't work...Could you please help me? I've been looking all over the internet for help, but nothing! The thing is, I can't use anything advanced- so just using if and while... Why isn't this working? here's the program:

```
   import java.util.Scanner;

public class Threeinon {

public static void Adding (int A, int B)
{   
    int C, D;

    if (A>0 && B>0) 
       {
       C=A;
       D=B;
       while (D!=0) {
            D=D-1;
            C=C+1 ;
       }
       System.out.println("The summation is: " + C);
       }



       if (A>0 && B<0)
       {
           C=A;
           D=B;

           while (D!=0)
           {
               C=C-1;
               D=D+1;
           }
           System.out.println("The summation is: " + C);
       }


       if (A<0 && B>0)
       {
           C=A;
           D=B;

           while (D!=0) {
               C=C+1;
               D=D-1;

           }
           System.out.println("The summation is: " + C);
       }

       if (A<0 && B<0)
       {
           C=A;
           D=B;

           while (D !=0)
           {
               C=C-1;
               D=D+1;

           }
           System.out.println("The summation is: " + C);
       }
}

public static void Multiplying (int A, int B)
{
    int C, D;

     if (A>0 && B>0 )
       {
           C=0;
           D=A;
           while (D!=0){
                D=D-1 ;
                C=B+C;
                System.out.println("The result is:" +C);
                System.out.println("The second result is true.");
           }
       }
       if (A==0)
       { 
           System.out.println("The result is 0");      
       }
       { 
       if (B==0)
       {
           System.out.println("The result is 0");
       }

       if (A<0 )
       {
           C=0;
           D=B;
           while (D != 0) {
               C=C+A;
               D=D-1;
           }
           System.out.println("the result is:"+C);
       }
       if (B<0 )
       {
           C=0;
           D=A;
           while (D != 0){
               C=C+B;
               D=D-1;
           }
           System.out.println("the result is:"+C);
       }

       if ( A<0 && B<0 )
       {
           C=0;
           D=B;
           while (D!=0){
               C=A+C;
               D=D+1;
               System.out.println("the result is:" +C);
               System.out.println("Only the first result is correct which is positive");
           }
       }

       }
}

public static void Dividing (int A, int B)
{
    int C, D;
    if (A>0 && B>0){
           C=0;
           D=A;
           while (D>=B){
                D=D-B ;
                C=C+1;
           }
           System.out.println("the result is:" + C);

           }

           if (A<0 && B>0)
           {
               C=0;
               D=-A;

               while (D>=B)
               {
                   D=D-B;
                   C=C-1;

               }
               System.out.println("the result is:" +C);
           }

           if (A>0 && B<0 )
           {
               C=0;
               D=A;

               while (D !=0 )
               {
                   C=C-1;
                   D=D+B;

               }
               System.out.println("the result is:" +C);
           }

           if (A<0 && B<0 )
           {
               C=0;
               D=-A;

               while (D != 0)
               {
                   D=D+B;
                   C=C+1;
               }
               System.out.println("the result is:" +C);
           }


}


public static void main(String[] args){

    int A=0, B=0;
    int n;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(" Enter 1 for multiplying");
    System.out.println(" Enter 2 for adding");
    System.out.println(" Enter 3 for dividing");
    n= scan.nextInt();

    if ( n==1 )
    {
        Multiplying (A, B) ;
    }
    else {
        if ( n==2 )
    {
        Adding (A, B);
    }
        else {
            if ( n==3 )
    {
        Dividing (A, B);
    }
        }

    }

       System.out.println("Ignore the two 0 you see, proceed");
       System.out.println("Enter first number:");
       A = scan.nextInt();
       System.out.println("Enter second number:");
       B = scan.nextInt();

      Adding (A, B);
      Multiplying (A,B);
          Dividing (A, B);
    }


}
```

Comment: don't work why? the result was not you expect or has errors? if have error show us the stack, otherwise if the result is incorrect show us what you have and what you wanted

Comment: What should that program do? Can you give us more specific description?

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? What error do you get?

Comment: What is the error you're getting?!

Comment: @X-Pippes When I run this and entered 1, then entered 2 and 8 and it was supposed to give me 16, and it gives me :14, 2, 10, etc. I just need one number, not 10 numbers...none of which were correct. There's no error on ecilpse, but before I run it it says there are errors...just doesn't show one (*Besides the "scan" is never closed)

Comment: @EelLee The program is supposed to ask what the user wants to do (+, * or / ) then the user gives the program 2 numbers and the program gives out the result. Three programs work perfectly on their own, but when combined all together...It's a mess.

Comment: @YeamFox and why don't you just use +, * or / ? Wouldn't that be...clearer?

Comment: @OblTobl then should I change n to what? (instead of int )? (I'm sorry I'm really a beginner )

Answer (score 1):

Why do you call your methods twice?
Maybe you try it this way:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

int A=0, B=0;
int n;

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println(" Enter 1 for multiplying");
System.out.println(" Enter 2 for adding");
System.out.println(" Enter 3 for dividing");
n= scan.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter first number:");
A = scan.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter second number:");
B = scan.nextInt();

if ( n==1 )
{
    Multiplying (A, B) ;
}
else {
    if ( n==2 )
    {
        Adding (A, B);
    }
    else {
        if ( n==3 )
        {
            Dividing (A, B);
        }
    }

}
}
```

By the way, don't you think it's much more easy if you shorten your methods a little bit? Or is this your purpose?
For Example:

```
public static void Adding (int A, int B)
{   
       System.out.println("The summation is: " + (A + B));
}
...
```

You can use the mathematical operators just as you are used to use them. `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`.
But pay attention to the division `/`. The result doesn't have to be an `int`, so better use `double` for your result.

Comment: @PeterLawrey yes...maybe it is. But i hope i just pushed him into the right direction and not solved it completely.

Comment: Yes this is homework, and my teacher said to only write these operations using the method of introducing C and D, and +1 and -1...this is pretty hard, I must say!!!! I have no choice...:((

Answer (score 0):

You don't ask the user to input A and B before you call `Multiplying`, `Adding` or `Dividing`. With the values initialized at zero, you won't get very interesting results this way.

As a stylistic side note, you should rename the methods to begin with a lowercase letter to better follow the usual convention.

Comment: But I've written other programs like this, they all seem to work. I've tried everything. The program is supposed to ask what the user wants to do (+, * or / ) then the user gives the program 2 numbers and the program gives out the result. Three programs work perfectly on their own, but when combined all together...It's a mess.

Comment: @YeamFox - if you think they worked perfectly on their own, you did not test them properly.  I can see a number of bugs ... not you mention some *absolutely atrocious* programming style!

Comment: @StephenC this is my 3rd program ever...I don't even know what I'm doing lol

Answer (score 0):

You are calling your choice of methods Adding, Multiplying and Dividing before A and B have been set to anything.  I suggest asking for A and B before attempting to perform an operation on them.

Answer (score 0):

```
int A=0, B=0;
    int n;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(" Enter 1 for multiplying");
    System.out.println(" Enter 2 for adding");
    System.out.println(" Enter 3 for dividing");
    n= scan.nextInt();
 System.out.println("Enter first number:");
       A = scan.nextInt();
       System.out.println("Enter second number:");
       B = scan.nextInt();
    switch(n){
      case 1:Multiplying(A,B);
      break;
      case 2:Adding(A,B);
      break;
      case 3:Dividing(A,B);
      break;
    }
```